# Weird problem with first person camera in Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

[Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oZdg_TfFrd8) is a video showing the problem.

For some reason the first person mode is really messed up, aiming a bow in third person is also quite strange.
I have tried a few first person enhancement mods and in the end disabled them all, I also installed the XP32 mod, but the problem still persists even after disabling all those mods.

Here is a list of mods that are installed through the Nexus Mod Manager.

[image: List of installed mods]

I have used these mods in the past on different Skyrim copies with no problems.

Comment: Are you sure the mods are actually not active in the game? Some need to be uninstalled manually.

Comment: They are not active.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the exact same problem. To add onto what akselmo said, it is indeed Immersive First Person View which causes the trouble. The problem is that you failed one simple but crucial step before uninstalling - making sure you were not in first person view. The fix is simple: load up the save with IFPV then switch to third person view and save and quit, then remove IFPV. That's it. It even says to do this on the [nexus page](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/49036/), something which I also initially missed.

Lesson learned: read a mod's uninstall guide before uninstalling because weird things could arise.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the Nexus Page:

> After uninstalling things are bad overall with first person view (camera in clouds, camera on horse feet, bow aiming goes extra far, camera is bouncing around, ...)
>
> Make sure the DLL file from Data/SKSE/Plugins/FirstPersonPlugin.dll got removed properly. Make sure you are not using Joy of perspective skeleton. Make sure you were not in my mod's first person view on that save game when you uninstalled.

So you might want to check for that .dll file

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall all mods and clear out all mod .esps from your Skyrim data folder. If the problem persists, and you are playing through steam, verify the integrity of the game cache.

Answer (score 0):

If you have had Immersive First person activated, make sure you have pressed the "reset defaults (show head)" in the SkyUI Mod Configuration settings.

I am not sure about the Joy of Perspective mod but if it has an uninstall button (some mods have these) in the same SkyUI Mod Config settings, press that first before uninstalling the mod completely.

So you may need to reactivate the mod, reset the mods settings to default/press the uninstall button, enable the normal first person view or third person view before saving and then quit the game and uninstall the mod.

Also make sure that even if it's deactivated in Nexus Mods list, it could still be active in the mod list. There could also be a SKSE script that you have to delete.

Answer (score 0):

The fix is a pretty simple one: You want to go to the save with IFPV, go to third person then save and quit, (MAKE SURE YOU SAVE OR IT WON'T WORK) And there you go... Simple as that!

Lesson Learned, Always, ALWAYS, Do what the mod uninstalling process says